# Flutter - Seleccionar un campo de una consulta en Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firestore

Estoy intentando seleccionar el campo de una consulta en Firebase para poder dirigirme a una pantalla u otra según el tipo de usuario que inicie sesión en mi aplicación.

Actualmente tengo la aplicación conectada a Firebase, por una parte tengo la autenticación y por otra la colección users en Firestore.

Me gustaría conseguir que según el email indicado, pueda saber su "access_level" y a partir de ahí enviarlo a la pantalla necesaria.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado una clausula where, la cual me saca el usuario cuyo email es el seleccionado, pero me gustaría saber el campo access_level de dicho usuario, el cual variará según el que inicie sesión.

```
CollectionReference users =
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
                
                
                var usuario = users.where('email', isEqualTo: "prueba@gmail.com");
```

Comment: revisa el tutorial, te ayudará mucho: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/

Comment: Muchas gracias, en ese mismo tutorial te dice que esa página está archivada, estuve intentándolo con la documentación "nueva" y no me funcionaba, con esa me ha ido perfecto!